# Tastypie PATCH requests have no effect, but return 202 ACCEPTED

Tags: python, django, curl, tastypie

I've got a custom user model and a resource endpoint, and for some reason, sending PATCH requests result in HTTP/1.1 202 ACCEPTED, but no change takes effect.

From reading the documentation, it seems like I should **not** have to manually grab the model and update the fields myself. E.g.:

```
AppUser.objects.all().select_related('api_key').set(params)`)
```

Rather, this should be built into Tastypie, correct?

http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#Resource.obj_update

It says here that ModelResource (which I'm using) has, "a full working version specific to Django’s Models". So what gives?

The curl request I'm making goes like this:

```
curl -X PATCH -H "Authorization: Basic XXX" -H "X-CSRFToken:XXX" \
--cookie "sessionid=XXX; csrftoken=XXX" --data '{"last_name": "meee"}' \
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/user/1/?format=json --verbose | python -mjson.tool
```

And from my models.py:

```
"""
Custom User Model.
"""
class AppUser(AbstractUser):
    """
    User model to which all other information about the user is linked 
    (e.g. the language they speak, the language they're learning, and 
    the submissions they make (submissions are stored in neo4j, see 
    api/submissions.py)
    """
    objects = UserManager()

    lang_learning = models.ForeignKey(Language, 
                            verbose_name='Learning Language', 
                            related_name='learning', 
                            null=True, 
                            help_text='Language the user is learning.')

    lang_speaking = models.ForeignKey(Language, 
                            verbose_name='Speaks Language', 
                            related_name='speaking', 
                            null=True, 
                            help_text='Language the user speaks.') 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.username) or u''
```

And the resource itself:

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    raw_password = fields.CharField(attribute=None, readonly=True,
                                    null=True, blank=True)

    lang_learning = fields.ForeignKey('api.language.LanguageResource', 
                                    'lang_learning', full=True, 
                                    blank=True, null=True)

    lang_speaking = fields.ForeignKey('api.language.LanguageResource', 
                                    'lang_speaking', full=True, 
                                    blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        authentication = MultiAuthentication(
            BasicAuthentication(), ApiKeyAuthentication())
        serializer = urlencodeSerializer()
        authorization = CustomAuthorization()
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'patch', 'put',]
        always_return_data = True
        queryset = AppUser.objects.all().select_related('api_key')
        excludes = ['is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'date_joined',
                    'last_login', 'password']

    def prepend_urls(self):
        params = (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash())

        return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/login%s$" % params, 
                self.wrap_view('login'), name="api_login"),
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/logout%s$" % params, 
                self.wrap_view('logout'), name="api_logout")
        ]

    def authorized_read_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        return object_list.filter(id=bundle.request.user.id).select_related()

    def get_list(self, request, **kwargs):
        kwargs['pk'] = request.user.pk
        return super(UserResource, self).get_detail(request, **kwargs)

    def obj_update(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
        """
        Maybe it's something here I need to be doing?
        """
        for field_name in self.fields:
            field = self.fields[field_name]

            if type(field) is fields.ToOneField and field.null and bundle.data[field_name] is None:
                setattr(bundle.obj, field_name, None)

        return super(UserResource, self).obj_update(bundle, **kwargs)

    def hydrate(self, bundle):
        try:
            raw_password = bundle.data.pop('password')
            if not validate_password(raw_password):
                raise CustomBadRequest(
                    code='invalid_password',
                    message='Your password is invalid.')

            bundle.obj.set_password(raw_password)
        except KeyError:
            pass

        return bundle

    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        if bundle.obj.pk == bundle.request.user.pk:
            bundle.data['key'] = bundle.obj.api_key.key

        return bundle
```

The full file is here:
https://github.com/OpenPhilology/phaidra/blob/development/api/user.py